# app.patch() is not working.get and delete is working but not patch.Is there any coding error what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, patch

> I want to create server which can perform CRUD.

> Movie model has only 1 property named title.

> I am able to create new movie,delete movie and search a movie by its _id.But update is not working.So,I have shown code below

> 1.GET and DELETE i have tested on postman and working properly.
>
> > [As i said get is working][1]

> 2.PATCH request is not working .
>
> > It is not even giving any response and just loading.

> localhost:3000/movies/id_of_movie
>
> > here id_of_movie is id of movie for update.

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
const express=require('express');

const  {mongoose}=require('./db/mongoose');

const bodyParser=require('body-parser');

const {Movie}=require('./db/models');

const app=express();

//middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"); 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
/* route handlers */
app.get('/movies',(req,res)=>{
    Movie.find({}).then((movies)=>{
        res.send(movies);
    });
});

app.post('/movies',(req,res)=>{
    let title=req.body.title;

    let newMovie=new Movie({
        title
    });
    newMovie.save().then((movieDoc)=>{
        res.send(movieDoc);
    });
});

app.get('/',( req, res )=>{
    res.send("hello");
});

app.patch('/movies/:id',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    Movie.findByIdAndUpdate({
        _id:req.params.id
    },{
        $set:req.body
    }).then(()=>{
        res.sendStatus({message:"success"});
    });
});

app.delete('/movies/:id',(req,res)=>{
    Movie.findOneAndRemove({
        _id:req.params.id
    }).then((removedMovieDoc)=>{
        res.send(removedMovieDoc);
    });
});
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````


[It is just loading and loading][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6LVa.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YauA7.png
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Any solution you found?

Answer (score 0):

Your express code looks fine, it could be that your mongoose query runs into an error which you are currently not handling. Node will run into an `UnhandledPromiseRejection` and the request will hang forever. Add a catch handler to your promise and handle your error, e.g.:

```
app.patch('/movies/:id',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    Movie.findByIdAndUpdate({
        _id:req.params.id
    },{
        $set:req.body
    }).then(()=>{
        res.sendStatus({message:"success"});
    }).catch(err => {
       res.status(500).send(err.message);
    })
});
```

Comment: @OP: any feedback on this?